# How to COPY CSV exports into a Redshift table that had a new column added?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have many CSV files in S3, but one of the tables had a new column added, so when importing those CSV files, we get an error "Delimiter not found. The new column is nullable and added to the end of the table so I'm hoping there's a way to import the old MySQL exports with NULL for the new table column.

Is there a way to do this without editing all the export files to add that column?

Answer (score 0):

You can map columns in a COPY command:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-column-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns that exist in your file in the COPY command (in the same order as they come in your CSV file). With the EMPTYASNULL parameters, columns with no data will get a NULL value.

```
COPY table_name (column_a, column_b)
FROM 's3://xxx'
CSV
[...]
EMPTYASNULL
;
```